# html5 storage not showing data on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a todo app storing the todo data in html5 storage. When I refresh the page the stored data is not displaying. Live site [here](https://fahaduddin.com/todo/). Please find code below,

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Todo</h1>
            <div class="add">
                <div class="text">
                    <input class="data" placeholder="Enter data">

                    </input>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <div class="submit-text">
                        Add
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
console.log("loads");
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(todo)).length;
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        count++;        
        localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify($('.data').val()));
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) { 
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i)+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
        }
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoitem", function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("strike");
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoremove", function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.todorow').addClass("hide");
    });
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) { 
        var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i))+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
        $(".container").append(value);
    }
});
```

style.css:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#000;
}
.header{
    background:#dddddd;
    height:200px;
}
.header h1{
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.add{
    height:50px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-left:1px solid #dddddd;
}
.text,.submit{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.text{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
}
.submit{
    width:30%;
    background:green;
    height:100%;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.data{
    font-size: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    /* padding: 10px 0; */
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:100%;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.submit-text{
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;
}
.todorow{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFF;
}
.todoitem{
    width:95%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.todoremove{
    width:5%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.strike{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your loop should just be: `for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {` because `count` is already the `.length` of the array in storage. And when getting the item from storage, `todo` should be in quotes so it is a string.

Comment: Also, why are you stringifying the `input` value? It's already a string. And, why are you getting the `.length` of the parsed value and using that as the basis for your loop counter? You have some fundamental issues with what you are storing, how you are storing and accessing it and what you are doing with it once it's accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap todo in quotes

```
var count=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo")).length;
```

Comment: This is definitely an error that will prevent the OP's script from working. `todo` without quotes references a variable namd `todo`, of which there are none. The OP is trying to read the storage value of "undefined" instead of the storage value of "todo," which explains why the desired value is not there.